# the code for pagging in data grid view in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#

m using the code

```
protected void Grd2_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{


    Grd2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    Grd.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

}
```

i have allow pagging = true
where Grd2 is my grid name
the pagging takes place on clicking 2 time....
i want the pagging should be on single click...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the Grid again after you have set the PageIndex.